# Prevent re-usage of Tomcat anti-CSRF token

Tags: tomcat, csrf, csrf-token

I implemented anti-CSRF tokens to my website:

`web.xml`:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CsrfFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>entryPoints</param-name>
            <param-value>/, /main.jsp</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>                    
            <param-name>nonceRequestParameterName</param-name>
            <param-value>CSRFToken</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CsrfFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

However, I can still manage to access some arbitrary site by, for example:

For a valid URL: `www.example.com/foo?CSRFToken=ABC123`

... substitute `foo` by `bar`.

It seems like the token can be re-used for like 5 times.

My question is, how can I set such number of re-usage times? Is the most secure way is to set it to 1?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The answer is to set

```
        <init-param>
            <param-name>nonceCacheSize</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>
```